# Android auto text reply using broadcast receiver sending multiple texts.

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

The following code sends a text to the incoming calling number, however it sends a different amount of texts every time. Sometimes it only sends one, but it varies up to 6. When monitoring my code while it functions I also get different numbers of broadcasts. What am I doing wrong?

Receiver:

```
package com.biapps.makin_biscuits;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Jake on 3/21/2016.
 */

public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "MyListener";
    private Context mContext;
    private Intent mIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;
        mIntent = intent;
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE;

        tm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);
    }

    private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override

        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

            Log.i(TAG, "number: " + incomingNumber + "");
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Incoming Call: " + incomingNumber + "",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                        SmsManager smsManager =     SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(incomingNumber, null, "I'm busy bruh", null, null);
                    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    tm.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);

            }

                   }
    };
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.biapps.makin_biscuits">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ContactsList">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Trigger" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.biapps.makin_biscuits;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //set object labels and states here
    private ImageButton icon;
    private AudioManager am;
    private ImageButton people;
    private ImageButton ring;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        icon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);
        people = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.people);
        //people.setOnClickListener(peopleButtonHandler);
        ring = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ring);

    }

    int buttonstate = 0;
    public View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (buttonstate == 0) {

                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonup);
                buttonstate = 1;
                am.setRingerMode(0);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Go!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
                intent.setAction("android.intent.action.Trigger");
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            } else {

                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.button);
                buttonstate = 0;
                am.setRingerMode(2);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Come back!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some code to recognize the previous state and determine whether or not to do the actions. This fixed the problem.

```
package com.biapps.makin_biscuits;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Jake on 3/21/2016.
 */

public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "MyListener";
    private Context mContext;
    private Intent mIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;
        mIntent = intent;
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE;

        tm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);
    }

    int previousState=TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
    private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override

        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

            int Call_State_Ringing = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            int Call_State_OffHook = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            if (Call_State_Ringing == state && Call_State_OffHook == previousState){
            Log.i(TAG, "number: " + incomingNumber + "");
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Incoming Call: " + incomingNumber + "",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                        SmsManager smsManager =     SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(incomingNumber, null, "I'm busy bruh", null, null);
                    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    tm.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);

            }

                   }
            previousState = state;
    }
};}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

you are registering `PhoneStateListener` inside onReceive(), so whenever your onReceive method invoked it will add one more `PhoneStateListener` to `TelephonyManager`. So, you have multiple listeners for the same event over the period.

What you can do is, you need to check if the listener is added before if so just skip that part.

Comment: How do I check for the listener?